# Foreign key error message in my SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE Parent 
(
    pID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PersonalNumber int NOT NULL,
    Phone varchar(50),
)

CREATE TABLE Student
(
    sID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PersonalNumber int NOT NULL,
    Phone varchar(50),

    -- causes error message
    FOREIGN KEY (pID) REFERENCES Parent(pID),
);
```

I get the error message:

> Foreign key references invalid table

How do I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have a pID in Student.

Comment: That fixed the error on "(pID)" But the same error remains on "Parent"

Comment: @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur Im using MSSQL

Comment: You have commas before the final `)`s.  It would not cause this particular error, though, but the code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the pID column in student table. Try this:

```
 CREATE TABLE Parent (
    pID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PersonalNumber int NOT NULL,
    Phone varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Student(
    sID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PersonalNumber int NOT NULL,
    Phone varchar(50),
    pID int,
    FOREIGN KEY (pID) REFERENCES Parent(pID)
);
```

Comment: That fixed the error on "(pID)" But the same error remains on "Parent"

Comment: Foreign key references invalid table 'Parent'

Comment: Please try now. I have removed a comma (,);

Comment: First create parent table. Then try to create Student.

Comment: It works when the Parent table doesnt exist. But if I've made the Parent table beforehand, and then create the student table, I get the said error message.

Comment: That's strange since I have successfully created both the tables. Which version of MSSQL you are using. Would you again look for any kind of typo please.

Comment: I hit execute with the error still there but it worked?? It says Query executed successfully. Thats weird

Comment: Please check table definitions. Should be ok.